# Rspec Passes when all tests are run, but fail when individual tests are run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I noticed something strange in my rspec testing.

When I run all my rspec tests, my tests that rely on my `require "plan_access_control"` statement pass, for example, AController, BController, and CController all pass.

However, if I run BController_spec.rb separately, it fails. How do I get my tests to run in isolation to each other so they should fail? My assumption is that once the `require` gets loaded, it's loaded for all tests, but this should not happen.

```
# controllers/concerns/access_controllable.rb
module AccessControllable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  require "plan_access_control"

  def validation_object
    @validation_object ||= PlanAccessControl::Validations.new(counts: 1)
  end
end


#lib/plan_access_control.rb
module PlanAccessControl
  autoload :Validations,     "plan_access_control/validations"
end

# lib/plan_access_control/validations.rb
module PlanAccessControl
  class Validations
    def initialize(counts:)
      self.counts   = counts
    end
  end
end

# controller/a_controller.rb
class AController < ApplicationController
  include AccessControllable

  def new
    @a = PlanAccessControl::Validations.new(counts: 1)
  end
end

# controller/b_controller.rb
class BController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @b = PlanAccessControl::Validations.new(counts: 1)
  end
end

# controller/c_controller.rb
class CController < ApplicationController
  include AccessControllable

  def new
    @c = PlanAccessControl::Validations.new(counts: 1)
  end
end
```

Comment: Since it's rails, I'd suggest adding this to autoload and get rid of the `require "plan_access_control"`. Any particular reason this can not be autoloaded?

Comment: Auto load the lib?  I heard that was not advised

Comment: But does it have to be in lib? If it does, configure your rspec to execute examples in random order (https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-9/docs/configuration/overriding-global-ordering) - then you'll discover this kind of dependencies.